# google maps map wont show up?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(18.133333, 21.566667);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 11,center: center,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN});
```

I have a DIV by the name map in my html.

```
    <div id="map"></div>
```

the JS is in a function called initialize in myscript.js which I reference in my index.html

-------------edit----------
google maps ref

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: can you show us how you add the reference to google map.,
did you try with within a dom ready handler?

Comment: sorry I dont get you, what do you mean by reference to google map.?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="" /> did you put sensor and api key?

Comment: are you getting any error messages in firebug? as Christophe said try to put it into a dom ready handler -> e.g. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: do the myscript.js is called after map api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a width and height on this div.

in HTML

```
 style='width:500px; height: 500px'
```

or in CSS

```
#map { width: 500px; height: 500px }
```

Comment: There is no error in what you've provided then. Check all basic stuff: - if google maps script is loaded before you try to use it, - if your script is even executed (add some _alert_ after it and check if it appears) etc.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you placed your google maps cdn AFTER your javascript cdns?

```
<!-- Add jQuery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add google maps API -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=place your api key here&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="assets/js/googleMapsApi.js"></script>
```